# Outlook does not display valid embeded images

Tags: php, image, outlook

I'm sending an email using PHP which contains an image. I know the resulting HTML is valid because it displays correctly HTML preview tools.

In Outlook 2013, all I see is the little red cross. I don't even get security warnings.

```
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
      </head>
  <body id="mimemail-body" class="mimemail-Testing">
    <div id="center">
      <div id="main">
        <p>Start</p>
<p><img alt="Red dot" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=="></p>
<p>End</p>
<p>s</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Is there a setting in Outlook I need to adjust?

I've tested with different images but I'm at a loss at how to debug this any further....

Comment: how are you creating and sending the email?

Comment: I'm using the Mime Mail within Drupal. It's converting IMG tags into Content Attachments, but images were not appearing, so I tried sending hard coded embeded images, just to see if that worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Outlook uses Word to display HTML, and Word does not support embedded binary images.

You need to attach the image as a regular attachment, set its Content-ID MIME header, then refer to that image in your HTML through the src attribute: src=cid:xyz, where "xyz" is the value of the Content-ID MIME header.

Comment: Ah. That makes things a little clearer. Thank you, I've give that approach a try.